# Test Request body of restTemplate.postforEntity(url, request,ResponseObj.class)

Tags: spring-mvc, junit, mockmvc, spring-mvc-test, springmockito

How can I test the request json passed in restTemplate.postForEntity.

Lets say for the below method:

```
    void doAsyncCall(Int id){
        MyObject obj= mydao.getObject(id);
        ///do something 
        MyRequstObject myrequet = constructRequestfromObject(obj);// set some thing in request object form obj

        Myresponse resp = restTemplate.postForEntity(url,new 
        HttpEntitiy(myrequet), respone.class)

        if(resp.status==ok){
            Logger.log("done");
        }
   }
```

AND in My test case:-

I want to test whats being passed to the postForEntity method in request.

**1) Its more like am I passing the correct Object and its properties to the post call.**

**2) Do we have any way of accessing request JSON in JUNIT to check the contract of what being passed**

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Mock the restTemplate in your test and call `doAsyncCall` and then verify if `restTemplate.postForEntity` is called with right parameter. To assert the object that is being passed to the method, you can you use `ArgumentCaptor.capture()`. For example:

```
    ArgumentCaptor<HttpEntity> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HttpEntity.class);

    verify(restTemplate).postForEntity(eq("some url"), captor.capture(), response.class);
    HttpEntity value = captor.getValue();
    assertEquals("content here", value.getContent());
```